# How can I add user profile fields to my mailpress mailout

Tags: plugins, custom-field, email

I want to be able to send emails to my subscribers but reference their name in the email and possibly some other profile fields.  Can I do this using mailpress?

So for example.  I want each email sent out to start with.

Hi *Tom*,

rather than

Hi,

I notice that you can add custom fields but couldn't work out how to relate that to a user profiles field at the time.

Answer (score 1):

This page seems to have the variables you need:

http://www.mailpress.org/wiki/index.php?title=Manual:Api:Mail

If you use `$args->toname` in your email code somewhere, that should display their name.

Please note that I just skimmed through the site and found this, so I can't guarantee it works since I don't know what your current code looks like nor have I used the plugin, but it looks like this is what you're looking for.